# Multithreading in python - urllib2

Tags: python, python-2.7

This is a simple script for doing request using multiple threads. I got it from http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/aix/library/au-threadingpython/.

How to put all the html of each requested page into a varible. I tried with a global variable and it doesn't work.

Comment: Instead of print soup.findAll(['title']) I need html.

Answer (score 0):

This is not the answer on your question, but i want to give you a little advice.
You can use [gevent](http://gevent.org) library for your task. Your code will be simplier.

And first of all you should read this [patterns](http://eventlet.net/doc/design_patterns.html).
Threads in python are evil. :)

Comment: I tried few hours ago but i couldn't install the gevent library. I got some strange error.

Comment: Windows ...unable to find vcvarsall.bat

Comment: did you try this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2817869/error-unable-to-find-vcvarsall-bat
can't help you with your problem, cause i use linux and mac os :(

Comment: with threads you can put your results (prints) in separate queue and after all get them :)

Comment: how to do this? Why global varible cannot get the value?

Comment: pass results_queue arg to threads __init__'s;  
i don't see global variable in your code

Comment: I do not know how to pass pass results_queue arg to threads init's. you could write an example if you know how to do it.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/49981/discussion-between-ellochka-cannibal-and-brana)

Comment: Never need, i have solved the problem another way. Thanks anyway.